# Intermediate level proof based math book.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I am studying linear algebra. I find elementary level linear algebra; i.e, concepts like vector spaces,basis, span dimension, solving determinants, finding Eigenvalues ,using Cayley Hamilton theorem, etc very easy. I am reading Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra done right. I have completed exercises upto Chapter 3 exercise D. But I find the exercises from the next section onwards, which are proof based and focus on abstract vector spaces very hard. I am unable to solve it without help. Part of the reason is I have never encountered this sort of mathematics before. I would appreciate if anyone can recommend books which introduce  proof based mathematics and abstract mathematical concepts, the books need not be based on linear algebra only, they can be based on other topics also.

Comment: Go back to the theorems in the previous chapter and try to prove them yourself, in the order they are presented. You will get stuck. Read the proofs in the book to see how they used concepts introduced previously to derive the theorems.

Comment: Try these: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/linear-algebra-notes/ I personally like them more than Axler's book in many ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also studying Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra done right*. The site https://linearalgebras.com/ is great because you can find the solutions for all exercises in the *Linear Algebra done right*. Before this book, I have read *A Logical Introduction to Proof* by D. Cunningham. However, *How to Prove It: A Structured Approach* by D. Velleman is better because you can find the solutions for all exercises in the web.

Answer (score 0):

there is a decent linear algebra book by Hoffman and kunze. You can check that. I don't know the level of the book you are reading now.